# Which codes can perform density functional perturbation theory (DFPT) calculations for a van der Waals (vdW) material?

Tags: density-functional-theory

I notice that most codes can only perform finite difference calculations when including van der Waals interaction. Are there any codes that can apply density functional perturbation theory (DFPT) in combining with van der Waals interaction? Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Bo

Comment: Do you mean van der Waal's functionals, or semi-empirical dispersion corrections?

Comment: Both are fine for me as long as they can provide a correction for the van der Waals interaction in graphite.

Answer (score 7):

**Unfortunately, these vdW correction schemes are currently not available for calculations based on density functional perturbation theory. Therefore, the following suggestion is meaningless.**

- You can combine VASP with phonopy to realize your purpose.
- VASP: https://www.vasp.at/
- Phonopy: https://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/
- [Here is an example](https://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/vasp-dfpt.html#vasp-dfpt-interface) of VASP+DFPT, all that you need do are put the van der Waals interaction [(IVDW)](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/wiki/index.php/IVDW) in the INCAR of VASP calculation (step 4).

Comment: In IVDW tag, it mentions that "Note, however, that these correction schemes are currently not available for calculations based on density functional perturbation theory."

Comment: I'm so sorry about that.